# Traefik IngressRoute is not accepting TLS certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have set up a TLS kubernetes secret which is operating normally on the non-traefik workloads.

When I try to use it to one of my ingress routes the certificate seems to have not been applied and the "**TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT**" is assigned.

Below is my IngressRoute .yaml

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: example-ns
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: example-svc
          port: 9090
  tls:
    secretName: example-tls
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Indeed issue was related with passing the TLS Store to both namespaces and traefik pod logged the below:

```
level=error msg="Default TLS Stores defined in multiple namespaces: [example traefik]" providerName=kubernetescrd
```

I removed the TLS store from the "example" namespace and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

If your cert is not availabel (or not match), then traefik will use `TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT`.

Please `sign new availabel certificate` to use.